# PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase return data when finish

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

i'm running some test on my forms with selenium/PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase

i'm testing a subscription form in the last step my website show an ID (for some reason)

```
    <html> 
    ....... 
    <h3>Your ID is : 1254686grd</h3>
    .......
    </html>
```

so in the end of the test i would like to return this ID .

any way to do this ?

i tried to use use this $this->source() but nothing is shown in the test console

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo $this->byCssSelector("selector")->text();
```

I tested with github:

```
class S2p_GoogleTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase{

    function setUp(){
        $this->setBrowser("phantomjs");
        $this->setBrowserUrl("https://github.com/");
        $this->setHost("127.0.0.1");
        $this->setPort(4444);
    }

    function testGithub(){
        $this->url('/');
        echo "\n";
        echo $this->byCssSelector(".heading")->text() . "\n";
     }

}
```

It prints:

[image]